# Does it make sense to test other service call?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a service `ServiceA` that calls `ServiceB` method which returns only boolean value. There are no condition based on that in `ServiceA` we only pass this value to other service. Does it make sense to write a unit test that verifies if this service is called?

```
class ServiceA {
    
    public void foo() {
        boolean value = serviceB.shouldVerify(value);
        // other code that uses this value
    }
}
```

The method `shouldVerify` from `ServiceB` is already covered with unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You should test your method in serviceB test since it is there that the logic is done. ServiceA has no idea what this method is doing so it is impossible to test. You should write your test in serviceA for the three case the method returns(true, false and exception)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have code that uses that value in `ServiceA#foo`, you have at least 2 branches: one for `true` and another for `false`. If you have those branches inside `ServiceA#foofoo`, then you should cover them with unit tests.

Comment: I do not, I only retrieve this value, and then pass it to other service which covers it with some tests.